# AngularJs. Problems with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having two tables witch renders data trough angularJs, coming from 2 c#-methods.
The tables are structured almost exactly the same. The first one below is used as I searchfield and the other one is used basiclly to render names.
My problem is that the first one works perfect, but the other one does not. And I don't see the problem. Any help would be appreciated. // Thanks!

Here are my two tables. (the first one is working)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js"></script>
            <div ng-app="searchApp">
                <div ng-controller="searchController">

                    @*first table works*@
                    <span style="color: white">Search:</span> <input data-ng-click="myFunction()" ng-model="searchText">
                    <table style="color: white" id="searchTextResults">
                        <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
                        <tr ng-show="!!searchText.length != 0" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
                            <td data-id="{{friend.id}}" data-ng-click="SendFriendRequest(friend.id)">{{friend.id.replace("RavenUsers/","")}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>



                    @*Does not work*@
                    <input type="button" value="Get friends requests" data-ng-click="GetFriendRequests()">
                    <table style="color: white">
                        <tr><th>Friend requests</th></tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="friendRequest in friendRequests">
                            <td data-id="{{friendRequest.UserWhoWantsToAddYou}}" data-ng-click="acceptUserRequest(friendRequest.UserWhoWantsToAddYou)">{{friendRequest.UserWhoWantsToAddYou}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

HERE IS MY SCRIPT

```
                <script>
                var App = angular.module('searchApp', []);

                App.controller('searchController', function ($scope, $http) {

                    //Get all users to the seachFunction
                    $scope.myFunction = function () {
                        var result = $http.get("/Home/GetAllUsersExeptCurrentUser");
                        result.success(function (data) {

                            $scope.friends = data;

                        });
                    };


                    //Get friendRequests from other users
                    $scope.GetFriendRequests = function () {
                        var result = $http.get("/Home/GetFriendRequests");
                        result.success(function (data) {

                            $scope.friendRequests = data;


                        });
                    };
                });

            </script>
```

The first script-function called `myFunction` works perfect and the data coming from my c#-method looks like this:

```
[{"id":"RavenUsers/One"},{"id":"RavenUsers/Two"},{"id":"RavenUsers/Three"}]
```

The second script-function called `GetFriendRequests` does not work, and as far as I can see there is no difference between this data passed into here than the data passed into `myFunction`:

```
[{"userWhoWantsToAddYou":"RavenUsers/Ten"},{"userWhoWantsToAddYou":"RavenUsers/Eleven"}]
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, cause I haven't tried it... but try the second http call with something like result2 instead of result and report back please.

Comment: @veroxii Thanks for your respond, but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you use `then` instead of `success` because `$http` returns a `promise`.

If your table doesn't "render" then put a breakpoint inside success function, console.log() the data or check `friendRequests` inside your HTML template, e.g. using `<div>{{ friendRequests | json }}</div>`, to ensure you actually got data from response.

Now you do not handle exceptions at all.

Example:

```
result.then(function(data) {
    console.log('got data')
  },function(error) {
    console.log('oh noes :( !');
});
```

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/KzY8A3

Comment: how do I pass my data into `$scope.friends = data;`
Like this, it doesn't work: `$scope.friends = [{"id":"RavenUsers/One"},{"id":"RavenUsers/Two"},{"id":"RavenUsers/Three"}];` Thank you

Comment: Actully when I added the `<div>{{ friendRequests | json }}</div>` I've got my correct data. So I got the response. What can be wrong then?

Comment: Thanks for your post, it is working now. I followed your instructions and got it working. The problem was under my tryouts, I still had the `track by userWhoWantsToAddYou` the advice @pfooti gave me (thanks anyway @pfooti, it was my misstake to left it in there). And thank you @Mikko Viitala

Comment: Thanks! I will use Plunker from now =)

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you either (a) provided a plunker to your code or (b) provided the error message.

ng-repeat requires a uniquificator on each item in the repeat, which defaults to item.id. If you don't have an id field on the item, you'll need to tell angular what field to use.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

So I'd suggest changing

```
<tr ng-repeat="friendRequest in friendRequests">
```

to

```
<tr ng-repeat="friendRequest in friendRequests track by userWhoWantsToAddYou">
```

and see if that works.

Comment: Again, make a plunk out of it w/ mock data and I bet you figure it out yourself. If not then it'll be that much easier for anyone to help out.

Comment: @MikkoViitala I've never tried plunker before. Did one try now but than nothing worked, sorry.

Comment: See if my updated answer help you. If not, then you can always "fork" simple plunks to get you going, e.g. here http://plnkr.co/edit/susiRn